# Using `reduce` or a ` forEach` as the most efficient way of merging an element into an array if it doesn't exist already

Tags: javascript

Suppose the following:

```
const getNewState = (state, messages) => {
    const messagesToMerge = [];

    messages.forEach((message) => {
        const alreadyInState = state.find((messageInState) => messageInState.id === message.id);

        if (!alreadyInState) {
            messagesToMerge.push(message);
        }
    });

    return [...messagesToMerge, ...state];
}
```

I would call the above like so:

```
const state = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'text 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'text 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'text 3'
    },
];


const newState = getNewState(state, [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'text 1'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'text 4'
    },
]);
```

The expected result:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'text 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'text 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'text 3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'text 4'
    }
]
```

Initially, however, I was using `reduce`:

```
const getNewState = (state, messages) => {
    const messagesToMerge = messages.reduce((acc, message) => {
        const alreadyInState = acc.find((messageInState) => messageInState.id === message.id);

        if (!alreadyInState) {
            acc.push(message);
        }

        return acc
    }, state);

    return [...messagesToMerge, ...state];
}
```

My question is which of these two is faster? I ask because I'd imagine that even though `state` is passed by reference to `reduce`, it's still cloned to be come the `acc`, and if there are, say 10,000 messages, then it must be slower that a simple `forEach`, right? Am I on the right track here or is there an altogether even better way of approaching this?

Comment: The answer to any "which of these two is faster" question is to measure it. However, no, `state` won't be cloned to become `acc`, your reduce will end up modifying it. Both of these approaches scales poorly; they're both O(n^2) or something due to the inner `.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

A more optimal solution: grab the IDs in the state into a set, and then filter  them out:

```
function getNewState(state, messages) {
  const idsInState = new Set(state.map((message) => message.id));
  const messagesNotInState = messages.filter((message) => !idsInState.has(message.id));
  return [...messagesNotInState, ...state];
}
```

Comment: This is an optimization suggestion, whereas the question was not asking us about ways to optimize the algorithm, but about comparing the performance of two existent algorithms.

Comment: @LajosArpad I beg to disagree since OP's post says "Am I on the right track here or is there an altogether even better way of approaching this?"

Comment: Since the question was about comparing two algorithms and the op described his reasoning, my understanding is that in the part you quoted he/she merely wondered whether there is a better way of thinking when comparing two comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to know what is the faster, as AKX said, just test it

I wrote the three tests in JsPerf [here](https://jsperf.app/layibi/3):

- forEach
- reduce
- AKX solution

The results are
[image]

**EDIT**: As AKX said, with a bigger amount of data (state 50 items, and 70 in stateToMerge), the fastest is the Set solution, and forEach is the slower

Comment: The second algorithm changes `state`. Is your test setting state to its initial state after each run?

Comment: I guess yes because the state is set in the setup section

Comment: My solution is slower for 2 items, yep. Try with a larger state.

Comment: @AKX Indeed, I updated my test and you are the fastest, nice catch :), answer updated too

Answer (score 1):

In order to actually measure them, you can loop with an index up to a very large number of your choice, perform both algorithms in the exact same amount and add up the times used for them. Then, compare the sums:

```js
let state = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'text 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'text 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'text 3'
    },
];
let stateJSON = JSON.stringify(state);
const getNewState1 = (state, messages) => {
    const messagesToMerge = [];

    messages.forEach((message) => {
        const alreadyInState = state.find((messageInState) => messageInState.id === message.id);

        if (!alreadyInState) {
            messagesToMerge.push(message);
        }
    });

    return [...messagesToMerge, ...state];
}
const getNewState2 = (state, messages) => {
    const messagesToMerge = messages.reduce((acc, message) => {
        const alreadyInState = acc.find((messageInState) => messageInState.id === message.id);

        if (!alreadyInState) {
            acc.push(message);
        }

        return acc
    }, state);

    return [...messagesToMerge, ...state];
}

let timeElapsed1 = 0;
let timeElapsed2 = 0;

for (let index = 0; index < 1000000; index++) {
    state = JSON.parse(stateJSON);
    let start = new Date();
    getNewState1(state, [
        {
            id: 1,
            text: 'text 1'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            text: 'text 4'
        },
    ])
    let end = new Date();
    timeElapsed1 += end - start;
    start = new Date();
    getNewState2(state, [
        {
            id: 1,
            text: 'text 1'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            text: 'text 4'
        },
    ])
    end = new Date();
    timeElapsed2 += end - start;
}

console.log("getNewState1: " + timeElapsed1 + " getNewState2: " + timeElapsed2);
```

For me, the sum was:

> getNewState1: 672 getNewState2: 705

You have an inner find, so the complexity is n * m, where n is the outer size and m is the size of data for which you run `.find`.

However, whatever the result, the first approach is superior, because the second modifies your array and prevents you from reusing it.

You can optimize your algorithm of course, but for the purpose of this question, you were wondering about the comparison of the two algorithms.

Comment: These comparisons make no sense when `state` has 3 items and `newMessages` has 2.

Comment: You can increase the input size, I have been using the op's input. But I think it makes sense even if the input is small, albeit with longer input we are more likely beyond the cluster point.